# jQuery - Reuse variable in a select

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, jquery-selectors

Say I have:

HTML:

```
<select id="mySelect"><option value="0">option-1</option>...</select>
```

JS:

```
var select = $("#mySelect");
```

and I further down, I want to do:

```
var val = $("#mySelect option:selected").val();
```

I've tried this, but it seems to only return the text, not the value attribute:

```
$(select + "option:selected").val();
$(select + "option:selected").attr("value"); // also doesn't work
```

Comment: You cannot concatenate a jQuery object and a String.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question: How I can reuse the object to get the selected option value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the .find() method.

```
var opt = $("#mySelect");

var val = opt.find("option:selected").val();
```

(just couldn't use "select" since it's reserved in so many languages)

This may be a little more efficient since you're not doing a new find each time.

Comment: This works. How efficient is find? Is this the most optimized way?

Comment: Find is the most efficient way to do this that I can think of.

Comment: From what I've read, it's better to do a single find instead of doing a new find each time, since it has to go through the entire DOM.  Going from an object you already have minimizes the search time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var strSelect = "#mySelect";
var val = $(strSelect + " option:selected").val();
```

Comment: It's not just the missing space, the `select` var is just a string. Narnian has a better solution in use of the `.find()` method, useful if you need `select` to actually be a jQuery object (i.e. if you're already performing some operations on it).

Comment: Is this space really needed? If so, some of the examples in the jQuery doc are wrong: http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: Sorry, not sure how the space got in the `option:selected` part. I was referring to the space *before* `option`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(select).find("option:selected").val();
```